# Div with SVG, column-lined two-row text, and underline, without inline code

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a universal "header-like" div that can be changed entirely within an external stylesheet. My website info is rather static and I just want the style/look to be dynamic, such that all I have to do is swap out the CSS linked and *bam*, the site is different.

I need my first version of this header-like div to look like this:

[image: Sakura Gakuen Header]

It's designed to look like your typical school letter head. The logo is an SVG and I'd prefer to use it thusly so it's easy to manipulate on the fly.

I originally had the image as an `<img src=...` line in the HTML file but realized that it's not very dynamic. It also made using an HR for my line kind of wacky, no doubt due to me doing it wrong. I tried making a `div` using the `background-image` property but it wasn't showing at all. I literally want the two lines of text to be separately configurable, re size and/or font weight/font family. I'd really, really, really love this to be done entirely within an external stylesheet, so, as I said, I could easily change this on the fly. I'd hope to be able to even include the text, as here "Sakura Gakuen", so the whole darned thing is dynamically changeable.

Is my idea possible fully? If not, what's the closest we can get to my idea? I don't care if @imports or whatever are required. I just want something statically dynamic, if that makes sense. Basically, a template page of my very basic and relatively unchanging text, and images/headers that change as the stylesheet called is swapped out.

The font I used there is EB Garamond and my SVG can be found [here](http://cafenocturne.com/images/svg/SakGakSVG.svg) and is sized to 100px width, and I want a padding on each side between the margin and "letter head" of 20px.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which part are you having trouble with?  Post what you have tried and if you have a particular problem you can't solve, ask about that.

Comment: That's the thing. I have _no idea whatsoever_ how to accomplish what I want so have no code to show as proof of concept. Everything I've thought of still requires a lot of the letter head concept to be coded in the HTML as well as the external CSS. I don't know how to call up my idea with just a `div` or `span`. It still requires `<img src=../images/svg/SakGakSVG.svg ...` and style declarations in the external sheet. I want as much of this thing shoved into the external sheet as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you were after?

```css
.letterhead {
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.letterhead::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://cafenocturne.com/images/svg/SakGakSVG.svg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.line1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.line2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 130px;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="letterhead">
  <span class="line1">Sakura</span>
  <span class="line2">Gakuen</span>
</div>
```

**Update:**

OP asked if the was:

> a way to get the text "Sakura Gakuen" into the external sheet?

Here's a version where the text is in the stylesheet.  Note that is generally not recommended. It is usually best if content and styling are kept separate.

```css
.letterhead {
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.letterhead::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://cafenocturne.com/images/svg/SakGakSVG.svg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.line1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.line2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 130px;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
}

.line1::before {
  content: 'Sakura'
}

.line2::before {
  content: 'Gakuen'
}
```

```html
<div class="letterhead">
  <span class="line1"></span>
  <span class="line2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not at my computer to test this but YES! This looks AMAZING! Thank you! I'll upvote/check it when I've tried it at my computer tonight. :)

Comment: This **_is_** brilliant code! It looks great! I was wondering if there's even a way to get the text "Sakura Gakuen" into the external sheet? I know that currently, the content property does not parse and thus, cannot be externally styled, but maybe I'm wrong or there's a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes it is very easy. I've updated the answer with how to do that.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! That is just beautiful and really helps me understand pseudo elements SO much better. What kind of Stack rewards am I able to confer on you for your patience and kindness? Is there some kind of "reputation gifting" where I award you some of my points or something? I sincerely want to thank you.

Comment: YW. No further thanks necessary. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks so very, very, comment-character-minimum-limits much! ;D

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve your goal. Here is one possible solution.

HTML code...

```
<div>
    <div class="logo">
        <svg class="logo-svg" viewBox="0 0 734 589" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            ....
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="letter-head">
        <div class="letter-head-text1">Sakura</div>
        <div class="letter-head-text2">Gakuen</div>
        <div class="letter-head-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code...

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-left: 10pt;
    padding-right: 10pt;
}

.logo-svg {
    width: 72pt;
    height: 72pt;
}

.letter-head {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28pt;
}

.letter-head-text1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.letter-head-text2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.letter-head-line {
    border-top: 4pt solid gray;
    width: 300pt;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to declare the SVG inside the external stylesheet, to keep as much of this letter head in the stylesheet and out of the HTML as possible?